# Selecting rows from current month mysqli & php

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a cell in my database which timestamps a task once complete, for reporting I am wanting to show the figure of row which result in the current month.

So for example there may be 10 tasks complete this month but I need to show that figure, I am trying to do this with the following but not even getting any output from it?

```
$sql="SELECT published FROM to_do_list WHERE MONTH(date)=MONTH(NOW())";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if ($result=mysqli_query($db,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
```

So there is a cell called `published` which is a DATETIME. the aim is to count and show how many rows contain the current month from that.

Comment: You're using `mysqli_query()` twice and that should be throwing you an error about it http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php so just do `if ($result=mysqli_query($db,$sql))` and get rid of the line above that and you'll be good to go ;-)

Comment: Someone's preparing an answer now, I feel it in my *Spidey sense*. It's tingling ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- haha - although by just using a single `mysqli_query` nothing is printing out still? Very odd and I have error reporting switched on plus I know for sure there are records in there for this month

Comment: `or die(mysqli_error($db))` to `mysqli_query()` doesn't reveal anything?

Comment: Well that did it! Stupid human error once again. Forgot to change date to published in my query...

Comment: ah, another happy ending ;-)

Comment: Thought I'd pop in an answer for it there Dan ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you're using `mysqli_query()` twice and that should be throwing you an error about it:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

So just do:

```
if ($result=mysqli_query($db,$sql))
```

and get rid of the line above that and you'll be good to go

Plus, as stated by the OP in comments after checking for errors:

> *"Well that did it! Forgot to change date to published in my query"*

As per another comment by one of Stack's great members:

> *"You might want to add that adding a check for the year might make the results a bit more reliable :-) – jeroen"*

Comment: You might want to add that adding a check for the year might make the results a bit more reliable :-)

Comment: *laughing loudly with a big smile* - Yes you did ;-) @jeroen